# How to handle an abstract enum?

Tags: c#

I am getting an exception on an abstract enum. I am new to C# and I am working with an existing application not made by me.

if I understand this correctly, the application wants to get a BehaviorType, and there are two types in the enum list.

```
namespace TaleWorlds.MountAndBlade
{
    public enum MissionBehaviorType
    {
        Logic,
        Other
    }
}
```

Visual Studio 2022 will automatically create a solution, but that solution ends up in an exception.

```
public override MissionBehaviorType BehaviorType => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

I cannot for the life of me figure out a way to get passed this. My last attempt was accepted by Visual Studio, but then stopped at an exception, because I don't know what I am looking for.

```
public override MissionBehaviorType BehaviorType { get { return BehaviorType; } }
```

If possible, could you explain the why as well as the how, so that I can add this to my "Now I understand" folder. Thanks!

Comment: In your final attempt at a fix, the property getter is calling itself, so it just calls itself infinitely until a stack overflow occurs and crashes the app.

You need to return either `MissionBehaviorType.Logic` or `MissionBehaviorType.Other` so that there's a valid value of the enum to be returned.

Comment: You have an override of an abstract or virtual property. Your `enum` is not abstract.

Comment: very minor - just a language thing (and I realize it might be "E2L", so please understand that I mean this constructively): it is "get past this", not "get passed this"

Comment: You *think* you're struggling with the syntax and trying to figure out which keystrokes go in which order to "just make it work"... But in fact the problem isn't syntactical at all.  Before you can "just make it work" you need to decide what you want it to *do*.  You're creating a class, which inherits from a class that has an abstract property.  So your class must implement that property.  When you implement that property, what value should it *return*?  It clearly can't return *itself*, as that would be infinitely self-referential.  So what *should* it return?

Comment: I'll start off by saying that returning MissionBehaviorType.Other, and through that I'm assuming the Logic as well, worked to get passed this. I need to take some time to digest what is actually happening here, since I am only a few days into C#.

Syntax was my biggest problem. I figured it needed one or the other but I had no idea of how to reply to it. I still don't understand why it is written the way it is, but that is for another issue I would imagine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't about "abstract enums" but rather: abstract members (in this case, an abstract property getter).

If an `abstract` type has an `abstract` member, then in order to create a non-`abstract` subclass, you *must* `override` that member to provide an implementation. It needs to know what you want to happen when that member is accessed. The IDE can help stub out the member, but it can't tell you what the right implementation is, hence the IDE spits out the correct signature but with `throw new NotImplementedException();` as the implementation. Your job is to *provide the implementation*.

So: what do you want to happen? What value should it return? Is there some fixed enum value? if so:

```cs
public override MissionBehaviorType BehaviorType
    => MissionBehaviorType.YourThingHere;
```

Alternatively, do you have a field or some other expression that can *compute* the correct value? If so, *do that*:

```cs
public override MissionBehaviorType BehaviorType
    => {your expression here};
```

Like the compiler, we *also* can't tell you the correct thing to return.

Comment: The way I understand it is, that I should somehow get the mission behavior type from the program rather than give it myself, and that there are two options, Logic and Other. I tried using Logic instead of Other in my solution that someone commented onto the original post, and the program crashed, so clearly me manually inputting it into the code is not the way to go in the future. 

I will take some time with this, since everything is new to me.